# Lyx theorem citations

Tags: lyx, brackets

I'm using Lyx and every time I add a new theorem (or lemma) it automatically adds square brackets after the theorem:

[image]

How do I remove those?

EDIT: I add a theorem the same way as a regular part, section, etc. I use Article (Standard Class) document type and Theorems(AMS) module. I tried changing to different theorem module, it did not help.

EDIT: I've made a mini example, here is the whole lyx file:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\onecolumn
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{psfrag}

 \allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}


\newcommand*{\horzbar}{\rule[.5ex]{2.5ex}{0.5pt}}
\newcommand*{\vertbar}{\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{\textbf{tr}}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options false
\begin_modules
theorems-ams
eqs-within-sections
figs-within-sections
customHeadersFooters
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package none
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding default
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 11
\spacing single
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_bookmarks false
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder false
\pdf_colorlinks true
\pdf_backref section
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\pdf_quoted_options "linkcolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=cyan,citecolor=black"
\papersize legalpaper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 2
\use_package amssymb 2
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 0
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 0
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle headings
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Theorem
here is theorem
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: You'll need to give us more information. Can you describe in detail how you add theorems?

Comment: I add a theorem the same way as a regular part, section, etc. I use Article (Standard Class) document type and Theorems(AMS) module. I tried changing to different theorem module, it did not help.

Comment: I just tried that, and I don't get the brackets. Can you make a minimal example, and add that to your question? That is, make a `.lyx` file containing just one theorem like that, open it in a text editor (e.g. Notepad, Textedit, Gedit, Kate), and copy-paste the entire content into the question.

Comment: You are very right, I don't know why didn't i think of doing this. I've added a code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added

```
\usepackage{theorem}
```

to your preamble. Remove this line.

The *Theorems (AMS)* module loads the `amsthm` package, and the combination of the two leads to the extra brackets somehow, as they are in conflict. The author of `theorem` recommends to not use it anyway:

> This pack­age is no longer rec­om­mended by its au­thor; he sug­gests users should use the AMS LATEX `am­sthm` pack­age in­stead; an­other widely-used al­ter­na­tive is `nthe­o­rem`q. (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/theorem)

---

Other comments: I'd remove `\onecolumn` and `\usepackage{graphics}` from the preamble as well. Single column layout is the default, and if you add an image via the LyX interface, LyX will load the successor package `graphicx` anyway.

Comment: After removing the "\usepackage{theorem}" it now there are parentheses '()' instead of brackets '[]'.

Comment: @AndreyGurevich Ehm, no. Not with the example you made, at least not on my system (TeX Live 2017, LyX 2.2.3). I get the expected "**Theorem 1.** *here is theorem*"